# conda environment pip is trying to install dependencies globally

Tags: python, pip, conda

Somehow my Python/Conda/Pip installation is such that pip - even when operating within an active conda environment - attempts to install to the global site-packages directory.

On my macbook pro running 10.12.4, I can reproduce by:

1. creating a conda environment: `$conda create -n test python=3.6`
2. Activating the conda environment: `$source activate test`
3. Verify that the pip command references the correct pip binary: 

   `$which pip
   /Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/pip`
4. Use pip to install any package - for instance numpy:

   `$pip install numpy
   Collecting numpy
   Using cached numpy-1.13.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
   Installing collected packages: numpy
   Exception:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
   status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
   prefix=options.prefix_path,
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
   **kwargs
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
   self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
   isolated=self.isolated,
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
   clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
   ensure_dir(destdir)
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
   os.makedirs(path)
   File "/Users/ethankeller/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
   mkdir(name, mode)
   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy'`

I imagine that some environment variable is set wrong somehow... Any advice on what could be wrong, or where to start looking?

Answer (score 5):

After struggling for a while, I was so willing to make myself clear of this issue, so I searched for a while, and just figured out and tested.

When you create a new conda env by specifying the python version, it will use the conda_root_python version. And if you didn't install the **pip** package, and try to use pip under your created conda env, it will only run the conda_root_pip and install the package in the root site_packages.

I know three ways to install python packages **only** in your created conda env.
For a better explanation, we create a conda env with same python version of conda root environment.

```
conda create -n myenv python
```

I. One of the officials advise, install package with *conda* command for specified conda environment,

```
conda install -n myenv tensorflow
```

II. Another one of official advise, get into your specified environment and run conda install

```
source activate myenv
conda install tensorflow
```

in above two ways you don't need to install extra packages like pip and other pip related packages.

III. For people who really want to **pip**, just because get used of that.
install pip package(just as above two ways did).

```
conda install -n myenv pip
```

or

```
source active myenv
conda install pip
```

then comes the pip install when you are in your environment

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score -1):

To install it globally you can use 
"sudo pip install numpy"

Avoid using sudo to save yourself a lot of trouble down the road. sudo will install the Python packages 'globally' and may overwrite existing installation, cause dependency errors and affect other users. Use virtualenv where possible, otherwise pip install  --user, this will install packages in the current user

```
pip install numpy --user
```