# Python Conda Environment confusion(as example: problem with gym)

Tags: python, pip, conda, environment

Trying to use gym open-ai package (and somen other) I ran into some problems,
which structure I don't really understand.

As an example:

I tried to install gym in three different conda environments.

One way to do this is
  pip install gym
Another is:
  git clone https://github.com/openai/gym.git
  cd gym
  pip install -e .

A third would be:
  pip3 install gym 
In some environments I would use Python2, in other env. maybe Python 3.7

Even more possibilities for installation would be:

sudo pip install gym

(and even more permutations would be possible, if we would take into account,
if we activate an environment or don't activate any environment).
To me things get even more complicated, because I tried to install conda with
a not-administrator-user-account in Ubuntu, so that conda (or rather the user itself could not install any files in the /usr directory). 
I began to test some of this possibilities and cases, because installation of some libaries
(e.g. keras-rl) seemed to need access to common ressources (/usr/ dir.), even if
installed in an local conda environment. But if so: would the installations in 
different conda-environments interact?
And what, if one would install a package as local user in a conda environment and 
afterward install a pip or pip3 as administrator. Would the admin-installation 
overwrite (or overrule or interact) the environmental installation (or parts of it)?

While experimenting with the different possibilities (or more: while trying to 
find a installations, which did not produce any errors like "gym not found" or
"attribute error ... " ) there did occur errors like:

```
Found existing installation: gym 0.15.4
Can't uninstall 'gym'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

after executing:

```
sudo pip3 install gym --force
```

So on this basis my questions specifically would be:

(1) Is there a best practice for establish good conda environments
(which don't tend to  interact, especially if some packages 
need sudo priviledges)?

And (2)  if some environments interact with 
general (sudo) ressources, how can they be resolved in a way,
that distinct environments can be tested and established beneath each other?

Annotation: 
there was a similiar question:
[conda environment pip is trying to install dependencies globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552507/conda-environment-pip-is-trying-to-install-dependencies-globally)
some time ago, but the advice,  not to use sudo,  seems to be difficult to follow, 
if some packages require access to global ressources. 
So I would like to ask for a solution to interactions at bit more specifically.

Comment: Edit PATH and remove  whats rest of gym maybe first.. activate env in cmd or whatever you use.

Comment: You got to activate the conda envirement every time you want to install a new pack. try to run conda update conda (check the documents might be like conda install update or something, been a while!

Comment: say you are inside pycharm. your env is active, there is a terminal there and it is impossible for the files not to be installed in the right place (no sudo) Am I selling this program? no, its simply the best and easiest safest way for someone who  have not already had to install it 1000 times and got mac, linux and windows on same machine. Only here to help do not feel bad about asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before. I activated conda envirement and installed with pip3 locally since conda does not have support for it. Warning: Possible of wreckig some packs.

The conda envirement should ALLWAYS be activated before installing anything orelse it ends up as a global installation.

install a new conda envirement without using sudo. If it ask for sudo you need to remove the whole thing and clean up a bit. Its very easy to forget and NEVER use sudo !

You can try installing a newer version of python3.x (python 2 is getting history very soon anyways they said. Pip = python2, pip3 = python3. And to answer one of your new question if by installing globally will mess things up, not outside conda.

google pycharm and conda. there you can just use it to install 3 different types of envirements with python. Actually a darn good editor for python coding. The rest is more linux related when we talk about cleaning up PATHS etc.

I have no better to add! Hope you get it right.

Comment: Thank you. I did do this:  remove the global egg file and then reinstall gym without sudo. This seems to work!

Comment: Stil I am confused about some aspects of conda: there are two versions for donwload: one for python 2, one for python 3. To get compatibility with some old tutorial files I downloaded the version for python 2. But with a new environment (without explicitly tell conda, which python version to take), it as default uses python3.7! Anyway, now it seems to work with gym, independent of the installed python version (even independend of using pip or pip3!).

Comment: they are removing python 2 from ubuntu etc kali even. its just outdated. dont learn 2 soon its "gone". From the officials. https://pythonclock.org/ many old scripts will be rewritten actually several hundread I think for kali linux.like windows 7 loses support the same is with python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

you should not use sudo to install something in a conda environment. Most likely the used pip command is not stemming from the actual (activated?) environment, but the actual system-wide pip is used. Therefore you would need to use to use sudo to install to a system owned prefix.

You can check whether you are using the desired pip by invoking "which pip". The path should point to your environment. If it does not, you shall install pip inside your conda env.

Comment: As an example: I have two different conda environments (both with Python3).

Comment: write conda install --name newenv python3.7.5 or the version u want:)

Comment: My last but safest advice is to use Pycharm and make a conda envirement just with a few clicks of a mouse (if all fails)

Comment: ..
In both envs I executed a pip install gym
Then I tested gym with the same python script. 
One version did run without problems, the other version showed  attribute-errors.
conda list showed, that gym existes in one environment and it does not exist in the other. And more confusing: pip uninstall gym or pip install gym does not change this!

Comment: lol same with me. One day I just reinstalled whole linux. And the gym package is the most ressisting thing ever sometimes cause its many other packs also. conda can crash badly with pip since pip will install gym to everywhere any python is installed unless inside the activated conda envirement!

Comment: @Mike75 I agree with Stian Diehard, if you’re having this many issue just use something like PyCharm. Keep in mind that Anaconda actually has a GUI tool for using Conda, named Anaconda Navigator.